# display fetched value in alert dialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display fetched value/s from db in alert dialog.
Here's the snippet where I fetched the data/s:

```
 final String url = "http://12.10.10.3/proj/fetch.php";

  List data = List(); 


  Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

    setState(() {
      data = resBody;
    });
   
  }
```

And here's the simple alert dialog code snippet.

```
 showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    
      Widget okButton = FlatButton(
        child: Text("OK"),
        onPressed: () { 
       Navigator.maybePop(context,true);
         },
      );

     
      AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
        title: Text("My  title"),
        content:  Text("Sample text"),
        actions: [
          okButton,
        ],
      );

   
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return alert;
        },
      );
    }
```

I have 2 columns in my Db which are value and description.
I tried putting data['description'] on the alert dialog content. But it gives me argument not assignable error.
Can someone help me. I'm new to flutter

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `data['description']` with a Text widget since the content parameter expects a widget.

Comment: That's what I did. And I got the argument not assignable error.

Comment: ```The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.```

Comment: ah ok so that means that data is not a Map (as you expect), but rather a List. Maybe you should try `data.first['description']`

Comment: It prints something but not the data I wanna get from DB. It says "defined as taking the property of another"

Comment: I tried to map it also like this
   content:  data.map((e) { 
        Text(
          e['description']
          );
          }),
But I got an error The argument type 'Iterable<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) for AlertDialog Widget. [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) is a stateless widget. This is the reason.

```
   StatefulBuilder(
       builder: (context, setState) {
           return AlertDialog(
                 title: Text("My  title"),
                 content:  Text("Sample text"),
                      actions: [
                                 okButton,
                               ],
                          );
```

You can read more from [this blog](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/05/hint-5-how-to-refresh-the-content-of-a-dialog-via-setstate/).

Comment: Sir, I still can't fetch the value. @Akif